# How can I take control of, or remove, an abandoned Facebook page for my Scout Group?

Tags: facebook-pages

Someone years ago created a Facebook page for our Scout Group. I’ve no idea who, there’s very little content on it, and we have another one that is live and in use anyway. The problem is, we keep getting told by parents and prospective parents they’ve been messaging this other page and not getting a response, which is obviously a problem.

None of the options for reporting this page really cover this situation as it’s not really breaking any rules. It’s not a business page so I can’t claim it through that process. What can I do to get Facebook to take this page down or give me control of it?

Comment: @pnuts thanks. Not much in there to help though. Strangely, there doesn’t seem to be anywhere on the page I’m talking about to view members/admins at all.

Comment: @pnuts This is the page in question: https://www.facebook.com/pg/FirstShirenewtonScoutGroup/posts/ I can't see anywhere to view the current membership of the page.

Comment: @pnuts there are some options around reporting it for kiddie porn or selling guns, neither of which apply, all other options just end in the suggestion to block the page.